# Spring Security SAML infinite retry loop on bad SAMLResponse

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-saml2

I am currently working on configuring Spring Security SAML extension (I am a Service Provider who wants to integrate with multiple Identity Providers).

I noticed bizarre behavior. When everything is configured correctly, federated login just works, and everything's perfect. But when there's a problem with SAMLResponse parsing, my app goes into a retry loop (which I have not configured anywhere). After a few hundreds of failed retry attempts, it returns 500 to a user. This dumps a ton of useless stacktraces into my logs.

The first SAMLResponse parsing error message contains an actual root cause. All others have the same info: InResponseToField in SAMLResponse did not match request Id in AuthnRequest. But this is very strange because in my browser I see only one request and one response (which appears after all retries finish and I receive 500). And ids match in those two requests.

first failure:

```
{"@timestamp":"2019-05-10T13:20:17.628+0300","level":"INFO","thread":"http-nio-8000-exec-2","logger":"org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger","message":"AuthNResponse;FAILURE;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;org:patkovskyi:test;http://www.okta.com/exkm1jqgci0YsCUgy0x7;;;org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Response doesn't have any valid assertion which would pass subject validation\n\tat org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:229)}
```

retries:

```
{"@timestamp":"2019-05-10T13:20:17.630+0300","level":"INFO","thread":"http-nio-8000-exec-2","logger":"org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger","message":"AuthNResponse;FAILURE;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;org:patkovskyi:test;http://www.okta.com/exkm1jqgci0YsCUgy0x7;;;org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: InResponseToField of the Response doesn't correspond to sent message a1cj420hf746f14746d8c2gb014a588\n\tat org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:139)}
```

Has anyone seen a similar problem? And is there some hidden retry mechanism in Spring Security SAML?